# ターミナル全域を使ったアプリの呼び方

Tags: linux

vim、less、manなどの、ターミナルの全域を使って表示制御を行っているアプリのことを一般的に何と呼ぶのでしょうか？

同じようなアプリを作るために情報収集したいのですが、そもそもどんな検索ワードで検索すればいいのかわかりません。

Comment: linuxではncurses（ncursesw）のライブラリを使っている物が多いと思われます。

Comment: [Console application - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

vim/viはスクリーンエディタ、more/lessはページャーと呼ばれてると思います。

情報収集が目的であれば terminfo termcap curses ncurses あたりを調べてみると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

「TUI」（Text User Interface）が近いかと思います。lessをTUIと呼ぶかどうかは微妙ですが。

Answer (score 1):

「俺テキストエディタ」を作ろうと思ったものの、途中で放置されたままになっているコードがありましたので、参考になれば。

```
/*

 ncurses example

 $ gcc -lncurses main.c

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int width;
int height;

void siginthandler(int param)
{
}

void print(int x, int y, char const *text)
{
    move(y, x);
    printw("%s", text);
}

void print_invert_line(int y, char const *text)
{
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(width + 1);

    int n = strlen(text);
    if (n > width) n = width;
    memcpy(buf, text, n);
    while (n < width) {
        buf[n] = ' ';
        n++;
    }
    buf[n] = 0;

    attron(A_REVERSE);
    print(0, y, buf);
    attroff(A_REVERSE);

    free(buf);
}

void print_title_text(char const *text)
{
    print_invert_line(0, text);
}

void print_status_text(char const *text)
{
    print_invert_line(height - 1, text);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    signal(SIGINT, siginthandler);
    WINDOW *win = initscr();
    raw();
    nonl();
    noecho();
    keypad(win, false);
    width = getmaxx(win);
    height = getmaxy(win);
    print_title_text("ncurses example");
    print_status_text("press enter to exit.");
    while (1) {
        refresh();
        int c = wgetch(win);
        if (c == 0x0d) {
            break;
        }
        char tmp[100];
        sprintf(tmp, "(0x%02x)", c);
        print(x, y, tmp);
        x = x + strlen(tmp);
        y += x / width;
        x %= width;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```